# Iterate over two dictionaries and get a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries (d3 and d4) and I want to see if the values of one of the dictionaries (d3) are in the keys of the another dictionary (d4) and in that case save the value of that dictionary (d4) into a new list.

```
d3 = {0: ['mo', 'A', 'la'], 1: ['tel', 'A', 'Al'], 2: ['Jak', 'E', 'Pum']}
d4 = {'ko' : 'Paul', 'la' : 'John', 'si' : 'Peter', 'Al' : 'Laura', 'gh' : 'Will'}
a3 = d3.values()
b3 = d3.keys()
a4 = d4.values()
b4 = d4.keys()
t = 0

for i in a3:    
if i not in b4 == -1:
    continue                 
else:          
    taxa = a4[t]
    t += 1 
print taxa
```

With this code I don't get the expected result, which should be:

```
taxa = ['John', 'Laura']
```

In the case that a value of d3 is not in the keys of d4, it would be nice if it could return 'unknown' in the list. So the ideal result in this case would be like this:

```
taxa = ['John', 'Laura', 'unknown']
```

I have searched other questions and although some of them are similar,I haven't found any one explaining one case like this one

Comment: Just a quick note. `if i not in b4 == -1` is always evaluated to `if False:`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it:

```
>>> d3 = {0: ['mo', 'A', 'la'], 1: ['tel', 'A', 'Al'], 2: ['Jak', 'E', 'Pum']}
>>> d4 = {'ko' : 'Paul', 'la' : 'John', 'si' : 'Peter', 'Al' : 'Laura', 'gh' : 'Will'}
>>> taxa = []
>>> 
>>> for l in d3.values():
...     v = next((d4[item] for item in l if item in d4), 'Unknown')
...     taxa.append(v)
... 
>>> taxa
['John', 'Laura', 'Unknown']
```

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) will return the first matched element from the passed generator expression. If nothing found, `'Unknown'` will be returned.

Those can be combined in single list comprehension:

```
>>> [next((d4[item] for item in l if item in d4), 'Unknown') for l in d3.values()]
['John', 'Laura', 'Unknown']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use set comprehensions and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) module.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d4 = {'ko' : 'Paul', 'la' : 'John', 'si' : 'Peter', 'Al' : 'Laura', 'gh' : 'Will'}
>>> d3 = {0: ['mo', 'A', 'la'], 1: ['tel', 'A', 'Al'], 2: ['Jak', 'E', 'Pum']}
>>> d3keys = set(chain.from_iterable(d3.values()))
>>> {value if key in d3keys else 'unknown' for key, value in d4.items()}
{'Laura', 'John', 'unknown'}
```

or

```
>>> [value if key in d3keys else 'unknown' for key, value in d4.items()]
['unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'Laura', 'John']
```